# MongoDB using .find to search through an array then .push pushes multiple times

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
     const names = cookie.currentMon.name;
        dexData.pokemons.find((pokemon) => {
            if (pokemon.name === names) {
              pokemon.amount += 1;
            } else {
              const dexobj = {
                pokemonID: poke.num,
                name: names,
                amount: 1,
              };
              dexData.pokemons.push(dexobj);
              dexData.totalPokemon += 1;
            };
          });
          dexData.save().catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

I have this code, and when the else statement is run it pushes the dexobj multiple times. If theres 2 previous docs, it will push 2 times. It basically doubles what is currently in the database. How can i search through the array of pokemon like this without the multiple pushes?

Comment: Is this inside another function that might be iterating?

Comment: No, its in its own function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed it to

```
const names = cookie.currentMon.name;
          const pokemon = dexData.pokemons.find(x => x.name === names)
            if (pokemon) {
              pokemon.amount += 1;
            } else {
              const dexobj = {
                pokemonID: poke.num,
                name: names,
                amount: 1,
              };
              dexData.pokemons.push(dexobj);
              dexData.totalPokemon += 1;
            };
          dexData.save().catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

and it works now